# Python backend -Securing REST APIs With Client Certificates

Tags: python, api, security, certificate, backend

We have a small website with API connected using AJAX.
We do not ask for usernames and passwords or any authentication like firebase auth.
So it's like open service and we want to avoid the service to be misused.

OAuth 2 is really effective when we ask for credentials to the user.

Can you suggest the security best practice and how it can be implemented in this context using python?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a firewall
Allow for third-party identity providers if possible
 Separate the concept of user identity and user account

Comment: How about Apigee ?